# Varying Due Dates in Workflow

Tags: workflow, tasks

Is there some way to vary due dates in an approval workflow?

For instance, if I have A, B, and C all on a serial approval workflow:

```
A: due date = today + 7 days
B: due date = completion of A's task + 4 days
C: due date = completion of B's task + 1 day
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each task outputs a variable that holds the list item id of the associated task.

When task A is complete, you can use that variable to look up the modified date of the task a list item and create a due date for task b. When task b is complete, you can use the variable output by that task to look up the modified date of that item to create a due date for task c.